# "or " operator in activerecord validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

[Activerecod validations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#combining-validation-conditions), says that I can combine condiitons and the validation happens if all my conditions are matched.

```
validates :foo, presence: true, if: "bar.present?", if: "baz.present?"
```

I have a scenario where I need to validate the presence of "foo" when either "bar" or "baz" are present.

I have worked around the issue making two validations:

```
validates :foo, presence: true, if: "bar.present?"
validates :foo, presence: true, if: "baz.present?"
```

Apart of looking ugly, this code will not scale when I will need to add more options. Is there a way to use the "or" operator and provide a hash of conditions, or anyway to make it look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll up about half a page in that guide you'll see two possible solutions: [Using a string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless) or [using a Proc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless):

A string:

```
validates :foo, presence: true, if: "bar.present? || baz.present?"
```

A Proc (the guide uses `Proc.new` but in Ruby 1.9.3+ we have the handy `proc` method):

```
validates :foo, presence: true,
  if: proc {|record| record.bar.present? || record.baz.present? }
```

Or, if you're using Ruby 2.0+ and, like me, prefer "stabby lambda" syntax:

```
validates :foo, presence: true,
  if: ->(record) { record.bar.present? || record.baz.present? }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to define method that responds to both attributes

```
validates :foo, presence: true, if: :has_baz_and_bar?

def has_baz_and_bar?
  [bar, baz].all?(&:present?)
end
```